# How to create an invalid file in Windows for testing?

Tags: visual-studio, file-io, embedded

I want to test if the disk scanning works fine for invalid files, and so I need to simulate invalid file with references to invalid cluster references.

I am using Windows CE and trying to test `ScanVolumeEx()` API. It has results in the `SCAN_RESULTS` structure and reports invalid files in dwInvalidFiles.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891858.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891883.aspx

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What actually qualifies as an _invalid file_?

Comment: give it filename longer than 260

Comment: In what way is this relevant to C, C++ or visual Studio

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  When something like this  happens
http://serverfault.com/questions/331779/how-do-i-debug-this-fs-error-on-a-flash-device

Comment: @CatchMeIfYouTry then you are asking how to corrupt the filesystem, programmatically?

Comment: @ryyker I am testing Visual C++ application using a DLL that has `ScanVolume()` implementation

Comment: @DrewDormann, It would be nice to do it programmatically, by modifying the FAT references, but any other options would be fine too.

Comment: The top answer in [the serverfault link you provided](http://serverfault.com/questions/331779) lists the common ways.  Cosmic radiation, writing a rogue driver, kicking the computer, etc.  Windows does not provide a direct API for corrupting the filesystem.

Comment: @DrewDormann I understand that. However, people have suggested writing FAT with junk, zeroing out first bytes (http://ask.metafilter.com/92393/I-want-to-corrupt-my-memory), and constant read/writes (http://objectmix.com/software-testing/81115-how-corrupt-compact-flash-file-system.html). I am just wondering if there are more convenient and easier ways.

Comment: ...wondering if there are more ***convenient*** and easier ways...- _fitting in well with a person's needs, activities, and plans._, _involving little trouble or effort_.  _near (to), close to, within easy reach of, well situated for, handy for, not far from, just around the corner from_.  Given these definitions of your criteria, a nail across boot area of platter, gravity - drop the disk from 2 meters onto concrete (I unfortunately have personal experience with this one. it works well). A huge magnet at close distance.  Any one of these will likely result in invalid files.  (tongue in cheek)

Comment: If it's removable media, find a Linux box and use `dd` as suggested in the ask.metafilter.com link.  That should take less than an hour even if you've never seen Linux before in your life and you have to download a live CD.  If it's NOT removable media, use whatever external tool you use to flash the media (and please don't put FAT on NAND, so lets hope it's MMC if soldered to the board....).

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, Thanks for that. I will try it. And also,it's actually FAT on NAND. Is using TFAT is what you are suggesting?

Comment: @CatchMeIfYouTry - Running *most* writable file systems directly on unmanaged flash is just inherently risky.  Erase blocks are typically large and bad blocks are a real thing that must be dealt with, and wear-leveling is usually a good idea. There's just a lot that can go wrong.... SD, MMC, SSDs, and various USB flash devices all "hide" this for you, so their generally preferred (though probably expensive per byte?) if doing a lot of writing.  Maybe WinCE has a robust enough NAND management layer to make FAT on NAND acceptable?  [to be continued...]

Comment: Even if WinCE *does* handle all the general problems in dealing with NAND, that does not guarantee the file system will be in a consistent state if you lose power / reboot.  Vanilla FAT16/FAT32 is particularly bad about issues caused by sudden power loss (even on managed flash, like SD).  Best case, you'll probably come up with the dirty bit set.  Theoretically TFAT solves those kinds of problems, but I've never used so I can't speak from first-hand experience.   If you have the option to use TFAT, you probably should.  

Further reading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa516909.aspx

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, I agree. We have two different systems. One uses FAT and the other uses TFAT. We have never seen issues on the one that uses TFAT.